# Ubuntu SDK: Where are the examples?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I am newbie to Ubuntu SDK.
Question: I want to see all the 57 Examples, but nothing to find.

Screenshot 1: [image]

Question: What does these error messages say in plain english?

Error1:
Starting /usr/ubuntu-sdk-dev/bin/qmlscene...
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Error 2:
:-1: error: securityolicy_groups_safe:Test7:debug: (REJECT) reserved policy group 'debug': not for production use.

Error 3:
Starting /usr/bin/autopilot3-sandbox-run... E: Xephyr executable not found. Please install Xephyr.
/usr/bin/autopilot3-sandbox-run exited with code 1

Please help!